# HRESULT E_FAIL error when doing batch geocoding in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geocoding

I am trying to write a batch geocoding application in **ArcObjects/C#** and keep getting the meaningless

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

error (`error code -2147467259`), and I can't figure out what's causing it.

Any tips on how to figure out what the error is? I am running `ArcGIS 9.3.1 SP 2`. Below is the code that I have. I get the error on the last line:

> `IRecordSet resultRecordSet =
>   geocodeServer.GeocodeAddresses((IRecordSet)recordSetInit,
>   addressProperties, null);`

Here is the full code:

```
        IGeocodeServer geocodeServer = null;
        IGISServerConnection conn = null;
        conn = new GISServerConnection();
        conn.Connect("mandarin");
        IServerObjectManager som = conn.ServerObjectManager;

        IServerContext geocoderContext = som.CreateServerContext("StateCntyLoc", "GeocodeServer");
        geocodeServer = (IGeocodeServer)geocoderContext.ServerObject;
        IGeocodeServerObjects gom = (IGeocodeServerObjects)geocodeServer;

        IGeocodingProperties locProp = (IGeocodingProperties)gom.AddressLocator;
        locProp.SideOffset = 0;
        locProp.EndOffset = 0;

        IServerContext gdbContext = som.CreateServerContext("MF", "GeodataServer");
        IGeoDataServer geoDataServer = (IGeoDataServer)gdbContext.ServerObject;

        IGeoDataServerObjects gdsObjects = (IGeoDataServerObjects)geoDataServer;
        IWorkspace gdsWS = gdsObjects.DefaultWorkingWorkspace;
        IFeatureWorkspace featWS = (IFeatureWorkspace)gdsWS;

        ITable addressTable = featWS.OpenTable("FACT_CRASH_INPUT");
        IFields fields = geocodeServer.GetAddressFields();

        // The Address Field Mapping is key = Locator Field Names and value = RecordSet Field Names
        IPropertySet addressProperties = (IPropertySet)gdbContext.CreateObject("esriSystem.PropertySet");
        addressProperties.SetProperty(fields.get_Field(0).Name, "INTERSECTION");
        addressProperties.SetProperty(fields.get_Field(1).Name, "CNTY_CD");
        IRecordSetInit recordSetInit = (IRecordSetInit)gdbContext.CreateObject("esriGeodatabase.RecordSet");
        recordSetInit.SetSourceTable(addressTable, null);

        IRecordSet resultRecordSet = geocodeServer.GeocodeAddresses((IRecordSet)recordSetInit, addressProperties, null);
```

Now if I put the table in a file geodatabase on my local machine and do the batch geocoding against **ArcGS Online**, I get back a record set.

```c#
        IAoInitialize ao = new AoInitialize();
        ao.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo);

        IGeocodeServer geocodeServer = null;
        IAGSServerConnection agsServerConnection = null;

        IPropertySet connectionProperties = new PropertySet();
        connectionProperties.SetProperty("Url", "http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services");

        IAGSServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory = new AGSServerConnectionFactory();
        agsServerConnection = serverConnectionFactory.Open(connectionProperties, 0);

        IAGSEnumServerObjectName serverObjectNames = agsServerConnection.ServerObjectNames;
        serverObjectNames.Reset();

        IName name;
        IAGSServerObject serverObject = null;
        IAGSServerObjectName serverObjectName = serverObjectNames.Next();
        while (serverObjectName != null)
        {
            if (serverObjectName.Name == "Locators/TA_Address_NA" && serverObjectName.Type == "GeocodeServer")
            {
                name = serverObjectName as IName;
                serverObject = name.Open() as IAGSServerObject;
                if (serverObject as IGeocodeServer != null)
                {
                    geocodeServer = serverObject as IGeocodeServer;
                    break;
                }
            }
            serverObjectName = serverObjectNames.Next();
        }

        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();
        IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(@"C:\Users\marni\Desktop\TestGC.gdb", 0);
        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
        ITable addressTable = featureWorkspace.OpenTable("FACT_CRASH_INPUT");
        IFields fields = geocodeServer.GetAddressFields();

        // The Address Field Mapping is key = Locator Field Names and value = RecordSet Field Names
        IPropertySet addressProperties = new PropertySet();
        addressProperties.SetProperty(fields.get_Field(0).Name, "INTERSECTION");
        addressProperties.SetProperty(fields.get_Field(1).Name, "CITY_CD");
        addressProperties.SetProperty(fields.get_Field(2).Name, "CNTY_CD");
        addressProperties.SetProperty(fields.get_Field(3).Name, DBNull.Value);
        IRecordSetInit recordSetInit = (IRecordSetInit)new RecordSet();
        recordSetInit.SetSourceTable(addressTable, null);

        IRecordSet resultRecordSet = geocodeServer.GeocodeAddresses((IRecordSet)recordSetInit, addressProperties, null);
```

Comment: addressProperties has 2 props for the first code listing, but 4 in the second listing.  Should it be that way?

Comment: As @Kirk said - It looks to me like the field mapping is incorrect in the first example (compared to the second), which would cause a failure on the line that @mfowler specified. Field mapping issues are notorious for generic errors.

Comment: The first example is using my locator, which only has 2 fields.  I have a locator that is using 4.  I just tried it with that locator and got the same error.  But I will double check my fields. The second example is using a predefined ArcGIS locator from tasks.ArcGisOnline.com. As far as I know, our locators are functioning correctly - we use them on a daily basis.  But I will try the first example using the locator from the second example to be thorough.

Comment: In the first code snippet, you're not co-creating a Recordset object, while you're doing that in the second. Try creating it the same way in the first snippet. You're required to do that. Read [this article](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriLocation/IGeocodeServer_GeocodeAddresses.htm) from ESRI.

Comment: @ujjwalesri - Thanks for the link.  I was able to compare what I was doing and I am doing the exact same thing.  The only difference is my address table is an SDE table, not in a file geodatabase.  In my examples, the second one works, its the first one that doesn't and that's the one I need to work because of the location of my input table.